# Adding 2 IconButtons next to the image

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a problem with my project. I need confirmation from the user for the location of this image. I want to make an object like this, would you be an investor?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n78Hm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be coded like this. And see working example [try it out!](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d7afd85fea7d2147beed43fb11745059)

```
Column(children: [
  Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Text('Here Image'),
    color: Colors.orangeAccent,
  ),
  Row(
    children: [
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text('First Button'),
        color: Colors.orangeAccent,
      ),
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text('Second Button'),
        color: Colors.orangeAccent,
      ),
    ],
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  )
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudo code

```
Column(
    Image(),
    Row(
        Button(),
        Button(),
    )
)
```